# How to log every web api request in Insights with .NET 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, .net-4.6.1

I have a `.NET Framework 4.6.1` solution which has this `global.asax.cs`:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    { Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = EnvironmentHelper.InstrumentationKey;

        HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }

    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _telemetry.TrackException(Server.GetLastError());
    }
}
```

This `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new InsightsExceptionLogger());
    }
}
```

This logger class:

```
public class InsightsExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
        {
            var ai = new TelemetryClient();
            ai.TrackException(context.Exception);
        }

        base.Log(context);
    }
}
```

And this is an example of a controller and method:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("api/v1/Something")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Something()
    {
```

The problem is I'm not getting any requests logged in Insights at all.

What do I need to do to get these API calls logged in Insights? (Assuming that simply adding `.TrackRequest()` is not necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Request Telemetry initializer` class and add the below code. On request Telemetry property you can select which `property` u want to add in a application insights.

[image]

After the Request Telemetry initializer class created add

```
<Add Type="webapptostoreloginappinsights.ReqTelemetryInitializer,webapptostoreloginappinsights"/>
```

in a `applicationinsights.config` file under telemetry processors

[image]

Make sure to call the request Telemetry initializer class in a `global.asax.cs`

[image]

Try to run the code now able to view the api request in a Application Insights

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What I ended up doing was this....

Add packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Ensure `web.config <system.web>` contains this:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
```

During the process the `ApplicationInsights.config` file was created and once deployed the application started logging `Reuqest` entries in Insights.